# React Native odd behavior to render FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

My goal is to render the 20 items in one go, instead of render 10 items and after 600ms re-render the 20 items again.

I make sure only render FlatList after the fetching is done. I rely on `React.useEffect` and the `data` depedencies to re-render, to simulate effect `load more when scrolling down`. The behavior is the same, when scrolling down, it re-renders the entire FlatList and re-render every 10 items.

console.log

```
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:56.797]  LOG      Album() useEffect()
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:57.510]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 1
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:57.651]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 2
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:57.758]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 3
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:57.851]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 4
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:58.700]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 5
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:58.175]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 6
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:58.272]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 7
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:58.375]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 8
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:58.525]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 9
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:31:58.654]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 10
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:04.758]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 1
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:04.940]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 2
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:05.106]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 3
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:05.240]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 4
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:05.420]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 5
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:05.530]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 6
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:05.608]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 7
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:05.737]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 8
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:05.885]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 9
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:05.986]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 10
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.310]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 11
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.920]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 12
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.148]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 13
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.201]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 14
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.280]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 15
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.340]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 16
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.414]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 17
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.457]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 18
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.521]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 19
[Tue Sep 15 2020 08:32:06.589]  LOG      Album() renderItem() render 20
```

./src/features/Album/index.js

```
import React from 'react';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  FlatList,
  RefreshControl,
  Animated,
} from 'react-native';

import Swipeable from 'react-native-gesture-handler/Swipeable';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    paddingVertical: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
  },
  separator: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#e4e4e4',
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
  leftActions: {
    backgroundColor: '#388e3c',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flex: 1, // continue to swipe.
  },
  actionText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 20,
  },
  rightActions: {
    backgroundColor: '#dd2c00',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    // flex: 1, // continue to swipe.
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
});

function LeftActions(progress, dragX) {
  // console.log('Album() LeftActions()', progress, dragX)
  const scale = dragX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 100],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  return (
    <View style={styles.leftActions}>
      <Animated.Text style={[styles.actionText, {transform: [{scale}]}]}>
        Add to Cart
      </Animated.Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function RightActions({progress, dragX, onPress}) {
  // console.log('Album() LeftActions()', progress, dragX)
  const scale = dragX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [-100, 0],
    outputRange: [1, 0],
    extrapolate: 'clamp',
  });
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
      <View style={styles.rightActions}>
        <Animated.Text style={[styles.actionText, {transform: [{scale}]}]}>
          Delete
        </Animated.Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

function Item({item, onSwipeFromLeft, onRightPress}) {
  // console.log('Album() Item() render')
  return (
    <Swipeable
      renderLeftActions={LeftActions}
      onSwipeableLeftOpen={onSwipeFromLeft}
      renderRightActions={(progress, dragX) => <RightActions progress={progress} dragX={dragX} onPress={onRightPress} />}

    >
      <View style={[styles.item]}>
        <Text>{`${item.id} ${item.title}`}</Text>
      </View>
    </Swipeable>
  );
}

function Separator() {
  return <View style={styles.separator} />;
}

export default function Album() {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = React.useState(1);
  // const [itemPerPage, setItemPerPage] = React.useState(20);
  const itemPerPage = 20;
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Album() useEffect()');
    fetch(
      `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?_start=${
        currentPage * itemPerPage - itemPerPage
      }&_limit=${itemPerPage}`,
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData((initial) => [...initial, ...json]))
      .catch((e) => setError(e))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));
  }, [currentPage]);

  // console.log('Album()', data);

  // question: VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 3179.666748046875, "dt": 627, "prevDt": 658}
  const memo = React.useMemo(() => renderItem, [data]);

  function renderItem({item}) {
    console.log('Album() renderItem() render', item.id);
    return (
      <Item
        item={item}
        onSwipeFromLeft={() => alert('swiped from the left')}
        onRightPress={() => alert('pressed right')}
      />
    );
  }

  function handleRefresh() {
    console.log('Album() handleRefresh()');
    setLoading(true);

    // simulate fetch
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1000);
  }

  function handleLoadMore() {
    // fake limitPage
    if (100 / itemPerPage === currentPage) return;
    console.log('Album() handleLoadMore()');

    setCurrentPage((page) => page + 1);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        <>
          {error && <Text>{error}</Text>}
          <Text>Album</Text>
          <SafeAreaView>
            <FlatList
              data={data}
              // Is this parameter bad for performance? Put it into perspective, it renders 1,5x more if this parameter is set to half.
              // initialNumToRender={itemPerPage / 2}

              renderItem={memo}
              keyExtractor={(item) =>
                '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + item.id
              }
              refreshControl={
                <RefreshControl
                  refreshing={isLoading}
                  onRefresh={handleRefresh}
                />
              }
              onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
              onEndReached={handleLoadMore}
              ItemSeparatorComponent={Separator}
            />
          </SafeAreaView>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how Flatlist works.

Flatlist is built on top of `virtualizedList` it does render only items that are visible to the screen and on a scroll, it will automatically remove/unmount the one which is out of the screen and thus providing an optimized approach to handle huge list.

But in your case, if it is going to be always 20 you can try setting `initialNumToRender` and mostly that should the work.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#initialnumtorender

further reading, https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration